# Creating a class which displays a getter from an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently having issues when accessing a getter method from an array of objects in another class.

```
public class Getters {

public double getTotal() {
double total = 0;
total=x+y+z;
return total;
}
```

I will be running a selection sorting algorithm which works and is successful in that regard.

```
public class Sort {
private Getters x[] = new Getters[21];
public void selectionSort() {
Getters temp;
    int minIndex;
    for(int i=0; i<=N-2; i++) {
        minIndex = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<=N-1; j++) {
            if(arrayObj[j].getTotal() < arrayObj[minIndex].getTotal())
                minIndex = j;
        }
        if(minIndex != i) {
            temp = arrayObj[i];
            arrayObj[i] = arrayObj[minIndex];
            arrayObj[minIndex]=temp;
}
}
```

This will now call my `getTotal()` and sort the object array based on the total number of points. My main method looks like this after the object is populated:

```
Sort x = new Sort();
Report y = new Report();
....
x.selectionSort();
y.displayReport();
```

Now I want my `displayReport` class to print out information regarding my object array, however I can't seem to write it. I haven't been able to call `getTotal()` in the new class, if I attempt to pass x to `displayReport` like this:

```
y.displayReport(x);
```

then I would setup the class `Report` like:

```
public class Report{
    public void displayReport(Sort x) {

   for(int i = 20; i > 15; i--) {
       System.out.println(x.getTotal());
       }
   }
 }
```

So my problem is that I am attempting to access `getTotal()` in the `Sort` class, however it belongs to the `Getters` class. In my main method I can't figure out a way to pass all the object array to the `Report` class so that I can let it access my getters.

Comment: In your Sort class, you can make a getGetter function which returns your array. Then in your report, you would do something like `x.getGetter().getTotal()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you do not have access to the field you are interested in. There are two ways to solve this. First you could simply set your `Getters x[]` field in the `Sort` class to public like so:

```
public Getters x[] = new Getters[21];
```

This would allow you to access `x[]` from the `Report` class with this line:

```
System.out.println(x.x.getTotal());
```

Here we are accessing the field `x[]` of the object `Sort x`.

This, however, is simply a band-aid solution. In Java you want to think about encapsulating your data, meaning you give a specific access case for every field in your class. If you set the field to public you will be able to access the data, yes, but in an undefined way such that other classes could access the data in a way you did not intend. This can lead to some nasty bugs.

You also may want to consider variable names which explain what the object they are referring to is, so instead of `Getters x[]` I might call it `Getters getters[]`.

Adding to this, my approach would be to keep the `x[]` field private and create a new method within `Sort` which simply returns it:

```
public Getters[] getGetters()
{
    return getters;
}
```

This not only encapsulates the data, it makes more sense when you write the line to access it inside the `Report` class:

```
System.out.println(x.getGetters.getTotal());
```